# Creating ManyToMany reference between db.Model and NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Changing question. I Want to apply `ManyToMany` relationship between `db.Model` and `NDB`.
example

`NDB` model

```
class my_NDB(search.SearchableModel):
   .......
   .......
```

`db` model

```
class Test(search.SearchableModel):
  email = db.StringProperty()
  created_by = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Can I apply `ManyToMany` relationship between these models?

EDIT:

Here is my `User` Model

```
  class User(model.Expando):
    """Stores user authentication credentials or authorization ids."""

    #: The model used to ensure uniqueness.
    unique_model = Unique
    #: The model used to store tokens.
    token_model = UserToken

    created = model.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = model.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    # ID for third party authentication, e.g. 'google:username'. UNIQUE.
    auth_ids = model.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    # Hashed password. Not required because third party authentication
    # doesn't use password.
    email = model.StringProperty(required=True)
    is_active = model.BooleanProperty(required=True)
    password = model.StringProperty()
```

And Here is my `Test` `db` model

```
class Test(search.SearchableModel):
  email = db.StringProperty()
  created_by = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Now I want to apply manyToMany on Test. Is it possible?

Django style ManyToMany

```
created_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: your question is really unclear. what do you mean you applied a ForeignKey between db and ndb?? manytomany between db.Model and ndb?? all this makes no sense.

Comment: Ditto. A class deriving from SearchableModel cannot be an NDB model class, since SearchableModel itself is a db model class. Can you take a step back and describe what your app has to do?

Comment: @Guido van Rossum Thanks for reply. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see. I had to look up the Django ManyToManyField docs. IIUC you want a Test to be created by multiple users, and of course each user can create multiple tests. Have I got that right?

The way to do this would be to have a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` in the Test class, so that the Test class has a list of keys -- where the keys point to User entities.

Now your User model is an NDB class, which complicates matters a bit. However the ndb Key class has an API for converting to and from db Keys:

- If you have an ndb Key k, `k.to_old_key()` returns the corresponding db.Key.
- If you have a db Key k, `ndb.Key.from_old_key(k)` returns the ndb.Key for it (it's a class method).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

PS. Please update your code to use `from google.appengine.ext import ndb` so you can write ndb.Expando, ndb.StringProperty, etc.